Window click through Flet
Is there any settings that would allow a mouse click to pass through the window? Somthing like: page.window_click_through = True?
(Body must be at least 220 characters; you entered 177.)
I searched the documentation and asked GPT
Update:
I was able to implement this with win32gui, flet doesn't seem to have this functionality. from the implementation it's probably better to understand what I mean:
def set_click_through(h, click_through):
    global is_click_through
    styles = win32gui.GetWindowLong(h, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
    if click_through:
        styles |= win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        is_click_through = True
    else:
        styles &= ~win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        is_click_through = False
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(h, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
